# Zend Form Error Message in Dialog Box

Tags: jquery, zend-framework

I have a zend Form which I am displaying in a jquery dialog box. It is working fine. One of my zend form field  has 'required' validation. Now problem is that when someone post the form without filling that field error message is not displayed inside dialog box rather it is displayed as normal action. I want to know how to display the error message in the jquery Diloag Box.

Comment: what you mean by this "rather it is displayed as normal action." ?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know how to display the error message in the jquery Diloag Box.

here is how : in your action just add :

`$this->view->errors = $form->getErrors();`

and then you put this array of error inside the jquery dialog

in the view script

```
<?php if (!empty($this->errors)): ?>
    <div id="dialog" title="Form Error ">
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($this->errors as $msg): ?>
                <ul><?= $msg ?></ul>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```